# Using PCA before classification

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, pca, random-forest, feature-selection

I am using PCA to reduce number of features before training Random Forest. I first used around 70 principal components out of 125 which were around 99% of the energy (according to eigen values). I got much worse results after training Random Forests with new transformed features. After that I used all the principal components and I got the same results as when I used 70. This made no sense to me since that is the same feature space only in difirent base (the space has only be rotated so that should not affect the boundary). 
Does anyone have the idea what may be the problem here?

Here is my code

```
    clc;
clear all;
close all;

load patches_training_256.txt
load patches_testing_256.txt

Xtr = patches_training_256(:,2:end);
Xtr = Xtr';
Ytr = patches_training_256(:,1);
Ytr = Ytr';

Xtest = patches_testing_256(:,2:end);
Xtest = Xtest';
Ytest = patches_testing_256(:,1);
Ytest = Ytest';

data_size = size(Xtr, 2);
feature_size = size(Xtr, 1);

mu = mean(Xtr,2);
sigma = std(Xtr,0,2);
mu_mat = repmat(mu,1,data_size);
sigma_mat = repmat(sigma,1,data_size);

cov = ((Xtr - mu_mat)./sigma_mat) * ((Xtr - mu_mat)./sigma_mat)' / data_size;

[v d] = eig(cov);

%[U S V] = svd(((Xtr - mu_mat)./sigma_mat)');

k = 124;
%Ureduce = U(:,1:k);

%XtrReduce = ((Xtr - mu_mat)./sigma_mat) * Ureduce;
XtrReduce = v'*((Xtr - mu_mat)./sigma_mat);

B = TreeBagger(300, XtrReduce', Ytr', 'Prior', 'Empirical', 'NPrint', 1);

data_size_test = size(Xtest, 2);
mu_test = repmat(mu,1,data_size_test);
sigma_test = repmat(sigma,1,data_size_test);

XtestReduce = v' * ((Xtest - mu_test) ./ sigma_test);

Ypredict = predict(B,XtestReduce');

error = sum(Ytest' ~= (double(cell2mat(Ypredict)) - 48))
```

Answer (score 1):

Random forest **heavily depends on the choice of the base**. It is not a linear model, which is (up to normalization) rotation invariant, RF completely changes behaviour once you "rotate the space". The reason behind it lies in the fact that it uses decision trees as base classifiers which analyze each feature **completely independently**, so as the result it fails to find any linear combination of features. Once you rotate your space you change "meaning" of features. There is nothing wrong with that, simply tree based classifiers are rather bad choice to apply after such transformations. Use features selection methods instead (methods which select which features are valuable without creating any linear combinations). In fact, RFs themselves can be used for such task due to their internal "feature importance" computation,

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was suspecting the same thing. I tried feature selection method (forward and backward elimination) however due to the number of features it runs to slow and its impractical. I could try to use feature importance from RF, as I can remmember there are several measures of feature importance in RF (percent selection frequency, mean score improvement etc) do you have any experience or advice on how to use them for best results?

Comment: unfortunately the reason behind existance of multiple criterions is the fact that their applicability highly depend on a particular data/problem so you will have to check at least few of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a matlab function `princomp` which would do pca for you. I would suggest not to fall in numerical error loops. They have done it for us..:)